# Error when trying to create mysql table on XAMPP

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp, create-table

I have a problem when I am trying to create a new table in phpmyadmin in a database. The code is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS phpcrawler_links;
CREATE TABLE phpcrawler_links (
  id           int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  site_id      int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  depth        int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  url          text NOT NULL,
  url_title    text,
  url_md5      varchar(255) NOT NULL,

  content      text NOT NULL,
  content_md5  varchar(255) NOT NULL,

  last_crawled datetime,
  crawl_now    int(11) NOT NULL default 1,

  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY idx_site_id(site_id),
  KEY idx_url (url(255)),
  KEY idx_content_md5(content_md5),
  FULLTEXT ft_content(content),
  KEY idx_last_crawled(last_crawled)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS words;
CREATE TABLE words (
  id     int(11) NOT NULL,
  word   varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

The problem seems to be on this line:

```
last_crawled datetime,
```

The error I get is:

> #1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

If anyone can help me out with this I will be greatfull!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google rules!
Only MyISAM tables support fulltext indicies.
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?107,194405,194677

Comment: Ok. And what can i do to solve this problem? I just need a little help to find a solution on this. Edit: I just had to add "ENGINE=MyISAM" before; on create?

Comment: Sorry for delaying. Yeah, you should supply ENGINE option in CREATE TABLE ddl. there is an example in url I gave.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot add index to that DB if the table is Innodb, you must change the engine to MyISAM or change the data type to int

Comment: I just added ENGINE=MyISAM" before ; on create table and it worked! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

seems you are using an old version of MySQL, as from MySQL 5.6, InnoDB support fulltext index already.